# Magic Fields - "Add an image" button in multiline editor is not working

Tags: wordpress

im using Magic Fields(Version 1.5.8.3) http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/magic-fields/ and i must say this is great plugin, but when i try to insert image into my custom field using "Add an image" button in multiline editor, when i press button "Insert Into Post" no image is insert.

Before i post this question , i also try to deactivated all plugin(except MF) and switch themes.

Screenshot : http://www2.picturepush.com/photo/a/10466810/img/10466810.jpg

Using wordpress 3.2.1

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After try to check my plugins version for Magic Fields i noticed, i need to downgrade my Magic Fields to version 1.5.8.1 because im using wordpress 3.2.1 this is compatible version for both .

Magic Fields Download Directory : http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/magic-fields/download/